# Mercurial GUI with support for evolve

Tags: gui, version-control, mercurial

I'm looking for a GUI frontend to the Mercurial version control system.  Right now I'm using TortoiseHg, which I dearly love, but it doesn't have any integrated GUI support for the `evolve` extension (e.g., folding multiple commits into one).  I'm basically looking for something that is exactly like TortoiseHG but has good support for evolve.

I have also used SmartGit, which supports Hg but also doesn't appear to have a GUI for evolve.  I have looked briefly at SourceTree but the fact that it now appears to require you to sign in with an Atlassian account is not attractive, and as far as I can see it doesn't have GUI support for evolve anyway.

I'm looking for a solution that is free of charge and ideally open source as well.

Also, hopefully this is obvious from the question, but just to be clear: I'm using *Mercurial*.  I don't want to use Git.  Git GUI frontends are not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

**TortoiseHg** does have some integrated GUI support for `evolve` these days: the workbench shows obsolescence relationships and troubled revisions, and the "Strip" command becomes "Prune" when `evolve` is enabled.

It doesn't yet support all the new commands like `hg fold`, or even `hg evolve`, but you can add those yourself using **Custom Tools**.

For example, try merging this into your `mercurial.ini` to get a context menu command to evolve specific revs, and a global command to evolve everything in the repo:

```
[tortoisehg]
workbench.revdetails.custom-menu = evolve-rev
workbench.multipleselection.custom-menu = evolve-rev
workbench.custom-toolbar = evolve-any-all
workbench.pairselection.custom-menu = evolve-rev

[tortoisehg-tools]
evolve-any-all.command = hg evolve --any --all
evolve-any-all.enable = istrue
evolve-any-all.icon = hg-extensions
evolve-any-all.label = Evolve Any/All
evolve-any-all.showoutput = True
evolve-any-all.tooltip = Evolves all troubled revisions.
evolve-rev.command = hg evolve -r {REV}
evolve-rev.enable = istrue
evolve-rev.icon = hg-extensions
evolve-rev.label = Evolve
evolve-rev.showoutput = True
evolve-rev.tooltip = Evolves the selected troubled revision(s).
```

Also, remember that you can type any `hg` command in TortoiseHg's console pane, and one CLI command can often replace multiple GUI operations. For example, to rearrange and combine a big stack of commits, you can run `hg histedit` once instead of rebasing and folding each one separately.